# Resttemplate android: RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found

Tags: android, json, resttemplate

I'm using Androd resttemplate and MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.
For some urls exchange works well, but one is causing exception.
Instantiation of Resttemplate

```
restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
rootUrl = "http://someserver.com"
```

and exchange function:

```
public Questions loadQuestQuestions(int quest_id, String token) {
    HashMap<String, Object> urlVariables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    urlVariables.put("quest_id", quest_id);
    urlVariables.put("token", token);
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json")));
    HttpEntity<Object> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(httpHeaders);
    return restTemplate.exchange(rootUrl.concat("/tasks/{quest_id}/questions?token={token}"), HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Questions.class, urlVariables).getBody();
}
```

Questions -

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonRootName;
import java.util.LinkedList;

/**
 * Wrapper for collection
*/
@JsonRootName(value = "questions")
public class Questions extends LinkedList<Question> {
}
```

`Question` having all needed annotations including `@JsonRootName`

Json comming have content type 'application/json' and all is right and recently works well.
But exception is thrown:
`org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [Questions] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your code. Spring 3.2.x added converters that use Jackson 2- `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`. Perhaps you could try this converter. This solved similar issues I had in the past. Make sure that your POJOs have Jackson 2 annotations. Hopefully that helps you.

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter map = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
messageConverters.add(map);
template.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
MyClass msg = template.postForObject(url, request, MyClass.class);
```